# Default configuration I need to change?

Tags: security, defaults

A few days ago I installed a new linux os. Today i realize `/root` has `o+r (755)` so EVERYONE is able to see my root sql password in `/root/.my.cnf`. I freaked out and simply changed `/root` to `750`.

My `/var/www` folder is `2755` but all the folders in it are `2750` (so certain users can browse to the folder without being blind). What software, file permissions and other DEFAULT configuration should I change?

Comment: Please specify the distro you installed. None of the ones I've used set /root to world readable.

Comment: @Keith: Really? Ubuntu 8.04 and Debian 6 both have root as readable to others.

Comment: Well, I don't use those. ;-)

Comment: @acid You sure? AFAIR Debian has never done anything like that (from an oft-unreliable memory), or at least as far as I started using it ~decade ago. Are you sure something didn't get screwed during daily usage? Was this a normal install? What exact OS are you using?

Comment: Always set the permission on files with passwords to 600 or 400.  The loosest permission I would allow is 640 or 440 if users in a specific group need access.  I have an ssl-certs group where this would apply.

Comment: @Tshepang: `/root` has always been 755 on Debian and Ubuntu, as far as I remember. My unreliable memory goes back to potato, and I can verify this for machines where the first install was etch, lenny, warty, hardy or lucid.

Comment: Guys, whatever if it does or not, the question is still the same. Its just an example. What else should i change? I change www-data cause sites need mysql which require useraccounts which can modify their site data. Which is why i limit what can read the www folders. What else can i do? Maybe theres a folder containing mail information i like to limit? maybe there are other things?

Comment: @Gilles Maybe I'm lost regarding these permissions thing, but `stat -c'%a %A' /root/` gives me `700 drwx------`. I don't remember ever being able to go into "**/root**" directory as non-root.

Comment: @Tshepang: Step 1: Download debian or ubuntu Step 2: Install it (perhaps on a VM) Step 3: look at the permissions for /root. Step 4: Wonder why you went through all this trouble when it has nothing to do with the question Step 5: Realize you dont have anything else to the thread ;)

Comment: @acid Oh, so one can go inside /root directory even though they don't have permissions to read the directory?

Comment: @Tshepang: There seems to be a difference depending on how you install Debian. When I used the Debian Squeeze NetInst while it was in Beta my /root is 755 but my pbuilder chroots have their /root as 700.

Comment: @Arr I normally use netinst, and I was never able to even view inside of `/root` with **`ls`**.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you should do a scan of your system with a tool like [tiger](http://www.nongnu.org/tiger/).  Tiger will pick up lots of things like this, and is a great way to get lots of advice and suggestions about how to secure your system.  Tiger can also be useful as a kind of Intrusion Detection System, too.

Comment: It didnt show me the 755 problem (i changed it to 755 for my second scan to see if it picks it up. it didnt) but i like tiger anyways so +1

Comment: hmm, well then I apologise!  it will go crazy if root's `~/.ssh` folder is world-readable, for example.  If Debian ships with `/root` as 755, and tiger doesn't warn about it, I would take that as a decent indication that it's not an unreasonable setting to operate with.